# update field in table if another field is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple table has 4 columns two of them dropdown menus with class= "ddm1" and "ddm2", what I need:

1. user can not select from "ddm2" before he select from "ddm1".
2. when user select any of these two dropdown menus, update flag column with a letter "g", else keep it empty.
   here what I tried :
   https://jsfiddle.net/yfzndsb3/1/

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('select option[value="0"]').attr("selected",true);

    $('.cf-table-block tbody tr').each(function () {
    $(this).find('.ddm1 option').each(function () {
     if(this.selected) {
      $('.ddm1 input').closest("tr").find(".flag input").val("g");
   }
    else {
    $('.ddm2').attr('disabled', true);
       }
      }
     });
    });
   });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I tried, let me now if this is what you need. You have a little mistake with the class attribute:

```
<td calss="ddm1">
```

but I made it different. (Also, you didn't load the jQuery library in your fiddle)

https://jsfiddle.net/yfzndsb3/4/